# SQL datetime and calendar.selectedDate in asp format issue

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, linq

I am building an appointment booking system web application in asp.net in VB,

Im simply trying to check whether an appointment has been made on a date selected from the calendar control.  I am using Linq for the bindings but the format from the calendar is mmddyyyy  when i need ddmmyyyy, my appointments entered int sql table as are 20/09/2012 10:00:00

trying to use a linq from p in db.apps
where p.date=mycontrol.selecteddate

does not yield results

some code added:-

```
 Dim myDate As Date = appCalender.SelectedDate



        Dim stat = From a In db.Appointments
                 Where a.dateAndTime = DateTime.Parse(myDate).ToString("ddMMyyyy")
                 Select New With {a.dateAndTime}

        Dim myList As List(Of String) = Nothing
        For Each a In stat

            myList.Add(a.dateAndTime)

        Next

        ListBox1.DataSource = myList
        ListBox1.DataBind()
```

im not sure if the code DateTime.Parse,,,, is right, there are many appoinments on the selected date which i select from the calendar but i think the DateTime format is not translating into SQL correctly

The appointment datatype in SQL is datetime

Comment: What did you try? Please, provide some code.

Comment: What is the type within SQL? If you're using an appropriate field type, and parameterized queries / LINQ, then you should be isolated from "database format".

Comment: Type in the SQL table is datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't comparing the same datatypes.

```
Where a.dateAndTime = DateTime.Parse(myDate).ToString("ddMMyyyy")
```

If the column in your database (and Linq) is a DateTime, the value on the right of the "=" is a string. It won't match up. Try this?

```
Where a.dateAndTime = DateTime.Parse(myDate)
```

EDIT

Also, it looks like you are only getting the Date from your calendar, not the time:

```
Dim myDate As Date = appCalender.SelectedDate
```

But you say your dates are stored as "20/09/2012 10:00:00"

20/09/2012 10:00:00 != 20/09/2012 00:00:00

Which is probably what is happening.

Try this

```
Dim myDate As DateTime =  DateTime.Parse(appCalender.SelectedDate)

Dim stat = From a In db.Appointments
           Where a.dateAndTime >= myDate And a.dateAndTime < myDate.AddDays(1)
           Select New With {a.dateAndTime}
```

Comment: Ive tried it and the format seems to return from myDate = #4/20/2012#, not sure why the parsing isnt working

Comment: What is the data type of a.dateAndTime?

Comment: the type is datetime,  as selected from the condensed datatype option in the visual studio 2010

Comment: @DavidRyan: It seems that the myDate variable is a DateTime?  If so, you should not need to call the Parse method.  Do you have Option Strict set to on in the project or at the top of the code file?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about what the format looks like when you view it - if you are comparing two things of the same data type, that should work. In your current code you are comparing a DateTime and a string.

Comment: This is really odd then, so the code without the parsing should work, unusual because i have a few records on the date ive chosen

Comment: @DavidRyan, I'm not a genius, I've just been doing this for a while... :)